# Print calendar appt without headings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing, calendar

I would like to open and print an appt from my outlook calendar.  However I am more interested in the notes section of the appointment.  I would like to leave out the header/start time/ location/etc... and just print the notes so that I can fit all the notes on one paper.